# Definition of planar isotopy of diagrams in a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3347.pdf) about graphical language in categories and at page 11 the author introduces this intuitive notion of planar isotopy for diagrams of a monoidal category. I can see the intuition behind this, but I would like a precise, formal definition of planar isotopy, which is referenced at [this article](http://maths.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/PlanarDiags.pdf). My question is: does the intuitive definition of planar isotopy given by Selinger correspond to Definition 2 of deformation of planar graphs given by Joyal and Street in the last article linked?

Comment: What makes you suspect they might differ?